# What happens when a person lowers their sleep to less than 3 hours a day?

Tags: sleep

If 6-8 hours would be required for a adult, how would less than 3 hours affect the person long term? If they can function well with less than 3 hours of sleep in the short term.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does night-sleep-deprivation have any effect on cognitive performance?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17843/7001) or [Sleep deprivation and task performance](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9444/7001) or [What is the permanent effect of sleep-deprivation on the brain and its cognitive function?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/26672/7001)

Comment: How much sleep is necessary on average for functioning ?

Comment: Check out [How much sleep is needed for peak cognitive performance?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9850/7001)

Comment: Toxic chemicals build up in the brain and would eventually cause the person to sleep or die after experiencing severe psychological/neurological symptoms like hallucinations.